# OpenRefine: How can I offset values? (preceding row to the following row)

Tags: offset, openrefine

Let's suppose I have this list in OpenRefine:

- A
- B
- C

Is there a way to move (offset values) B to A like the following?

- A  B
- B  C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `cross()` function, and v3.5 of OpenRefine (currently in beta) you can access previous or following rows by not supplying the field name. You can achieve the same by creating an index column in v3.4.

So, you can do `cells.ColumnName.value +" "+ cross(row.index + 1, "", "")[0].cells.ColumnName.value` to get the value of the next row appending the value of that cell in the current row, with a space.

Note that this will take the value of the row with an index higher, not necessally the row following in the display, if you use sorting.

Regards, Antoine